# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.on server

Tags: php

I am  runing an php mvc project on server on localhost it is working fine . but when i uploaded the same project on server it is giving the following error ,not getting any kind of clue

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

Comment: give permission 777 to that folder in which file is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give that folder permissions to 777

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reasons of this

1)folder does not have permission, so need to provide permission on this like:-
 sudo chmod -R 0777 folder-path

2)Check for htacess file reside in this folder with deny permission

Comment: do not add sudo if ubuntu is lower version